# LFTP and SFTP not working using crontab

Tags: linux, cron, sftp, lftp

I am using below script :

```
script_home=/home/insetl/ppp_scripts/prod/VSAVS
date_var=`date +'%Y%m%d' -d "0 days ago"`
date_var1=`date +'%Y%m%d' -d "1 days ago"`

lftp<<END_SCRIPT
open sftp://213.239.205.74
user sftpvuclip LW?T8e62
set xfer:clobber on
get Vuclip_C2B_TRX-${date_var}0030.csv
bye
END_SCRIPT
```

sudo grep -v '^ACC' $script_home/Vuclip_C2B_TRX-${date_var}0030.csv

> /home/insetl/ppp_scripts/prod/VSAVS/Vuclip_C2B_TRX-${date_var}.csv

scp $script_home/Vuclip_C2B_TRX-${date_var}.csv $TARGET_HOST:/tmp/

psql -h $TARGET_HOST -d $TARGET_DB -p 5432 << ENDSQL
delete from vsavs_offline_revenue_dump  where update_date like '${date_var2}%';
copy vsavs_offline_revenue_dump from '/tmp/Vuclip_C2B_TRX-${date_var}.csv' with   delimiter as ',';

update fact_channel_daily_aggr a
set revenue_from_file = (select sum(substr(amount,3)::float) from   vsavs_offline_revenue_dump where to_char(to_timestamp(update_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy' ),'YYYYMMDD') = ${date_var1})
where product_sk = 110030 and
a.date_id=${date_var1};

ENDSQL

The script runs completely fine when run manually. However the LFTP/SFTP part of the script doesnt run when ran through crontab. Please advise the solution for the same.

Output :

/home/insetl/ppp_scripts/prod/VSAVS/sftp_pull_in.sh: line 9: 08/02/2017: No such file or directory
20170209
/home/insetl/ppp_scripts/prod/VSAVS
grep: /home/insetl/ppp_scripts/prod/VSAVS/Vuclip_C2B_TRX-201702090030.csv: No such file or directory
DELETE 0
COPY 0
UPDATE 20

Comment: Redirect an output to a file and show us.

Comment: This is the output  and it excludes the lftp part                                                                              20170208  
/home/insetl/ppp_scripts/prod/VSAVS  
grep: /home/insetl/ppp_scripts/prod/VSAVS/Vuclip_C2B_TRX-201702080030.csv: No such file or directory

Comment: What grep? There's no grep in your script.

Comment: This part of code is after the one i have written in question as ....echo $script_home
sudo grep -v '^ACC' $script_home/Vuclip_C2B_TRX-${date_var}0030.csv > /home/insetl/ppp_scripts/prod/VSAVS/Vuclip_C2B_TRX-${date_var}.csv
scp $script_home/Vuclip_C2B_TRX-${date_var}.csv $TARGET_HOST:/tmp/

psql -h $TARGET_HOST -d $TARGET_DB -p 5432 << ENDSQL
delete from vsavs_offline_revenue_dump  where update_date like '${date_var2}%';
copy vsavs_offline_revenue_dump from '/tmp/Vuclip_C2B_TRX-${date_var}.csv' with delimiter as ',';

ENDSQL

Comment: Include both the output and the complete code into your question (there's "edit" link below the question text). We cannot read this!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Pls help

Comment: Format your question to be readable! + What is `/home/insetl/ppp_scripts/prod/VSAVS/sftp_pull_in.sh`? There's no reference to it in your code. Is it the path to the script itself?

Comment: Yes it the path of the script itself

Comment: But we can hardly know what the "line 9" refers to, as you have posted the script broken. Format your question correctly!